# Stick buttons on some positions in an image

Tags: android, image, zooming, photo, imagebutton

I basically need a photo (with zoom options that I almost have using this entry of the blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) and the possibility of interaction with some parts of the photo.

Lets say that I have a world map and I want to click in the different countries and go to their Wikipedia information. How can I stick some image buttons to a certain position of the image? (the zoom should also affect the buttons, I think it's clear with the example of the world map).

Every kind of information/idea is welcome.

Thanks,
Adam S.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straightforward:

1. Use AbsoluteLayout (within another main layout of course) to "layer" the buttons on top of an image.
2. In the pinch gesture, add appropriate calculations for the button coordinates and sizes

Comment: Thank you Vaayu for the answer, but AbsoluteLayout appears as deprecate in Andoid's documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html
should I still use it or maybe they've created an alternative?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no straightforward alternative. You can use RelativeLayout with creative use of margins to achieve similar results. Other alternatives are to use FrameLayout or to create your own custom layout which emulates AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: did you achive something with this solution? I'm working on something similar and can't get to have a basic solution to start dev... merci